# integrate $\int \frac{x^{(2n-1)}}{(1+x^2)^{(n+3)}} dx$

Tags: calculus

So, I need to integrate $\int \frac{x^{(2n-1)}}{(1+x^2)^{(n+3)}} dx, n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I've tried partial fractions, but I get nowhere.

Then I tried using substitution, using the substitution $t = 1+x^2$, but I get:
$$
\int \frac{x^{(2n-1)}}{(1+x^2)^{(n+3)}}dx = \int \frac{x^{(2n-1)}}{(t)^{(n+3)}} \frac{1}{2x}dt =2\int int\frac{x^{(2n-2)}}{(t)^{(n+3)}}dt = 2\int\frac{(t-1)^{(n-1)}}{(t)^{(n+3)}}dt $$

And then I don't know what to do.

Should I use another approach, or am I on the right path?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Finding an antiderivative for this will be a real pain in the butt. If the integration bounds are $(0,\infty)$ I believe there is a formula
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^p}{1+x^q}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{q}\csc\left(\frac{1+p}{q}\pi\right)$$
Assuming necessary convergence conditions are met.

Comment: @K.defaoite Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I= \int \frac{x^{(2n-1)}}{(1+x^2)^{(n+3)}} dx =\int \frac{1}{x^7(\frac 1{x^2}+1)^{n+3}}\, dx$ 
Now substitute $t=1+\frac 1{x^2}$ so that $dt=-\frac{2}{x^3 }dx$ and $I= -\int \frac{(t-1)^2}{2t^{n+3}}\,dt=-\int \frac{t^2-2t+1}{2t^{n+3}} \,dt$ 
Can you finish?

Comment: Yeah, I can finish from that, but could I ask where that $x^7$ came from? and how $x^{(2n-1)}$ became $(t-1)^2$? (I know that $x^{(2n-1)} * x^3 = x^{(2n+2)} =  x^{2(n+1)}$)

Comment: @Rararat: $(1+x^2)^{n+3}=(x^2(\frac 1{x^2}+ 1))^{n+3}=x^{2n+6}(1+\frac 1{x^2})^{n+3}$.  So you are left with $x^4$ in denominator. And $\frac 1{x^2}= (t-1)$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Denote
$$
I_n = \int \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(1+x^2)^{n+3}} dx.
$$
Using integration by parts it's easy to see that
$$
I_n = \int \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(1+x^2)^{n+3}} dx = \begin{bmatrix} u = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n+3}} & dv = x^{2n-1} dx \\ du = - \frac{2(n+3)x}{(1+x^2)^{n+4}} dx & v =\frac{x^{2n}}{2n}\end{bmatrix} = 
$$
$$
= \frac{x^{2n}}{2n (1+x^2)^{n+3}} + \frac{n+3}{n} \int \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(1+x^2)^{n+4}} = \frac{x^{2n}}{2n (1+x^2)^{n+3}} + \frac{n+3}{n} I_{n+1}. 
$$

Therefore,
$$
I_{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+3} \left(I_n - \frac{x^{2n}}{2n (1+x^2)^{n+3}} \right)
$$
and one can compute $I_n$ for any $n>1$ knowing $I_1$.

Comment: Thank you a lot!